# Do READ ONLY file groups reduce locking

Tags: sql-server

In a regular DB (i.e. Not Read Only), does putting tables in read only file group reduce locking when they are accessed?

E.g. Make separate file group as Read Write, create and populate tables, alter file group to read write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No .

Read only Filegroups doesn't prevent/Reduce locking(I assume we are talking only about shared locks,since no other statements are not possible)..

Locks can be prevented **only** ,when the database is set to read only

Read only file groups locking aspect has been covered here :[Read-Only filegroups and Locking](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2007/01/08/read-only-filegroups-and-locking/)

```
use general
go


alter database general add filegroup foo
go

alter database general add file (
name = file1,
filename = ‘c:tempfile1’)
to filegroup foo

— create a table and associate it to a filegroup
create table t_fg (c1 int, c2 int) on foo
insert into t_fg values (1,1)

— mark the filegroup read-only
alter database general modify filegroup foo read_only

— run a transaction with repeatable read isolation
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin tran
select * from t_fg where c1 = 1

— no check the locks
sp_lock @@spid

— here is the output
spid   dbid   ObjId       IndId  Type Resource                         Mode     Status
—— —— ———– —— —- ——————————– ——– ——
53     10     1381579960  0      RID  3:8:0                         S        GRANT
53     10     0                 0      DB                                     S        GRANT
53     10     1381579960  0      PAG  3:8                           IS       GRANT
53     10     1381579960  0      TAB                                   IS       GRANT
53     1      1115151018   0      TAB                                   IS       GRANT
```